# Trying to HttpPost a file in Android to my server

Tags: java, android, file, file-upload, http-post

This is roughly the code I'm working with now:

```
List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>(2);
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("json", json.toString()));
nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("blob", file.getAbsolutePath()));
post_request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameValuePairs));
```

The the reply I get back from the server is good for the first `add()` statement but, for the second one I'm not trying to send the path, I'm trying to send the file. Taking off `.getAbsolutePath()` should do the trick, but It won't let me as it only accepts strings. How would I go about sending the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should use a MultipartEntity, not an UrlEncodedForm one. In a Multipart body you can store objects of different mime types

Comment: The only time I ever use `UrlEncodedFormEntity` is as shown in my code. If I simply switch that to a `MultipartEntity` it does not work. Eclipse doesn't recognize it.

Comment: You need the jar for Apache httpmime. Also see [this blog post](http://linklens.blogspot.it/2009/06/android-multipart-upload.html)

Comment: I always find it difficult to find the exact .jar files when someone mentions them. Could you verify if this would be the link to download from?
http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.httpcomponents/httpmime/4.0-alpha3

Comment: Sure, but you don't need that old alpha version :) [this](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpmime/index.html) is the project home. Note that it's a module of a component of the Apache HTTP client project :) what a mess there...

Comment: So I click on "Dependencies" from the webpage you sent me and then..?

Sorry, but I honestly don't know my way around this whole thing. Not sure where the .jar file is located =(

I appreciate your time though.

Comment: It's not your fault, that site is badly designed. [go here](http://hc.apache.org/downloads.cgi) and download the latest non-alpha HttpClient GA in zip or tgz archive format. I think it will contain the jar (sorry I'm browsing from my phone)

Comment: Alright, I think I'm almost there. I extracted the zip, but now I'm looking for the jar and I really don't see it anywhere. Any suggestions?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9342/discussion-between-raffaele-and-eghdk)